# Freezing (Avoid Re-Drawing) a MapView In a Multi-Tab/Multi-MapView WPF Application

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a WPF application with two different MapViews in two different WPF tabs.

When I switch tabs between the first and second MapView items, the MapViews completely reload the base map and all layers.You can see it happening.

Is there a way to make the MapViews static so that they don't have to re-draw every time you switch from one MapView tab to another?